# Vertically centering unordered list and button in fixed width div

Tags: html, css, centering

I'm working with a div 300px wide, which contains an unordered list of icons which must span vertically, as well as a button.

What would the HTML/CSS need to look like to:

A) Have the unordered list float left and be centered vertically, and
B) Have the button to the right of the UL, vertically centered as well?

HTML:

```
 <div class="hb-left">
 <ul>
 <li><img src="cat.jpg"></li>
 <li><img src="dog.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="mouse.jpg"></li>
</ul>
<button>Demo</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hb-left {
 width: 300px;
height: 50px;
}

.hb-left Ul {
float: left;
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.hb-left button {
height: 40px;
float: left;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `button` and `ul` are set to `display: inline-block` you can simply use the CSS `vertical-align` property.

```
.someClass {
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle;
}
```

For further reading on `vertical-align`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

> The vertical-align CSS property specifies the vertical alignment of an ***inline or table-cell box***.

With the objects display set to `inline-block` you shouldn't need to use `float` by using `inline-block` elements should arrange next to each other so long as the parent div is wide enough. I would also suggest adding a fixed width to your inline elements to fit inside the `300px` parent div